# Create Order Totals - Remove currency symbol in Admin Panel

Tags: magento2, admin, adminhtml, totals

I've added custom totals "Total Weight". It works perfectly on the storefront but in admin panel it displays currency symbol $ and it is formatted with .00. How can I change it? It should be not formatted and prefix $ should be replaced with postfix "lbs".

[image]

Comment: Show your code.

Comment: https://www.siphor.com/add-a-custom-total-in-magento-2/ I used this example. My code is exacly the same.
As a workaround I overrided module-sales/view/adminhtml/templates/order/create/totals/default.phtml. Every custom total is wrapped with method formatPrice() there